# Filter for google_scc_notification_config resource

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to set up continuous export from scc to pubsub topic. While using the terraform resource google_scc_notification_config , I am trying to set up the filter so that it includes all the values . Has anyone been able to set this one in terraform so that all values ( i.e active , inactive all ) ?

Code example

```
resource "google_scc_notification_config" "custom_notification_config" {
  config_id    = "scc-findings-export"
  organization = "*******"
  description  = "Export"
  pubsub_topic = "ref-to-pub-sub-topic"

  streaming_config {
    filter = var.scc_notification_filter
   
  }
}
```

Lokking for a suotable value for scc_notification_filter variable to include all possible data.

Comment: Please post questions showing your work and a clearly defined problem. This guide will help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley , updated the question with code snippet.